# The timeline view has disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know where TO press, but the timeline view is gone
I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, but it still doesn't work
How do I get it to show up
My computer is Win10
I tried to install GitLens but was prompted to install the latest Git
I installed the latest version of Git and it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try `View/Open View...` and enter Timeline?

Comment: hello
I tried, but when I opened the view, there was no timeline option